# Formatting resume in LyX

Tags: header-footer, lyx, margins

I am writing a resume in LyX (compiled using MiKTeX). How can I place my name at the top and centered? Also when I output it in PDF, there is always a huge margin space at the top. How can I set the margins?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to set the header (and/or footer) the way you want. Add the following to your document preamble (`Document` -> `Settings...` -> `LaTeX Preamble`):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancyhead{}% Clear all headers
%\fancyfoot{}% Clear all footers
\fancyhead[C]{My Name}% Place "My Name" in Center of header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
\pagestyle{fancy}% Set page style to "fancy"
```

[image]

My code example only modifies the header, although you can do the same for the footer, if needed. Those commands are commented out.

See [Setting document width in LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5134/setting-document-width-in-lyx) in order to find out how to adjust the page margins according to your needs. Follow `Document` -> `Settings...` -> `Page Margins`, deselect `Default Margins` and enter your desired margins.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. To revert to default do I just clear LaTex Preamble?

Comment: To revert back to the default *margin* settings, you check the `Default Margins` box. To revert back to the default headings, you can clear the `LaTeX Preamble`, yes. If this doesn't work for you, most things can be updated in the preamble to fix it.

Comment: Just a question: I'm trying to add an image in the header the same way that Lyx adds images regularly in the document (`\begin_inset Graphics`) but it's not working out, only plaintext seems to work in the header. What am I doing wrong? I also tried placing the image with `\includegraphics` but that does not work either.

Comment: @bigbadonk420: What "does not work either" about using `\includegraphics`? Do you have `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your preamble? Are you inserting the content as an ERT? What compiler are you using and what type of image is it?